# Alternate to Redirect Page

Tags: jquery, html, .htaccess, history.js

I am attempting to figure out how to do history state manipulation and I saw a site that had a nice feature that if you put anything after the slash, the site will still load but in an incomplete state due to a flaw in the state machine. I was wondering how do you get the site to catch the address and forward like that? My only guess is to change the .htaccess file, but I'm not sure where to start for that...

http://bufmi.org/ (this is the site)

http://bufmi.org/about (this is the example of a site)

http://bufmi.org/foobar (this still loads the site, but not an actual page)

They have it set up that no matter what you put in after the slash it goes to the site, how did they accomplish that?

Comment: Have you looked at the javascript used on the page yet?

Comment: Yeah @hopkins-matt... actually this was an old project of mines and I wrote the state machine that this site uses a long time ago. I have the source files, but I feel that the answer lies in the 404 error and redirecting from the .htaccess files.

Only i could only use it with hash signs because of my limited amount of knowledge. Tho i use history JS, that was one thing i couldn't figure out is the redirecting.

Comment: Oh. I think I misread. So you are not trying to replicate the incomplete loading of nonexistent pages. You are trying to forward those nonexistent pages to 404 instead of the incomplete page?

Comment: I might be losing my mind...  Ignore the last comment. You want the incomplete state instead of a 404, right?

Comment: Yes... that is exactly what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achieved by some script that fires depending if you are at the root URL or not and a `.htaccess` rewrite rule to add the hash to anything other than the base url.

The `.htaccess` part is handled with something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /#$1 [NE,R]
```

This section of [scripts.js](http://bufmi.org/js/scripts.js) is responsible for the root URL check looks kind of like this:

```
if (document.URL == urlroot){
    //Applies Class to set of elements
    $('.example').removeClass('example-class', 0);
} else {
    //Applies Class to different set of elements
    $('.example2').removeClass('example-class', 700);
}
```

If you are not at the root URL a series of `if/else if` check to see if the content for the fragment identifier exists. If it exists, content is loaded into a specific section on the page from one [html file](http://bufmi.org/master.html) using anchors on that page. If the fragment identifier does not match any of the `if/else if` sections in [scripts.js](http://bufmi.org/js/scripts.js), then the anchor `Blank` on the `mater.html` page is used to display an empty content section.

Comment: Yeah i don't think i explained this clearly, it's not about how to build a state machine, they have it so that no matter what you put in after the slash it goes to the site, how did they accomplish that?

Comment: Awesome, is there anything I can try to help clarify further?

Comment: No no... this was everything. The .htaccess file rewrites the Rule that uses a regular expression and converts whatever is after the host URL and turns it into a hash, effectively forwarding it back to the site which is exactly what I was looking for. I never knew you could do this with .htaccess files, so I apologize about my confusion.

Comment: No problem. I was confused too. ha ha

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature available since Html5.

You can override default actions.

Here is an implementation with jQuery :

```
$( document ).on( 'click', 'a', function( e ) {

    // prevent the page reload
    e.preventDefault();

    // change the content of the <body> tag
    changeContent($(this).attr('href'));

} );
```

Forward and Back buttons of the browser are handled like this

```
window.addEventListener( 'popstate', function( e ) {

    // Change the content of the <body> tag
    changeContent(location.pathname);

} );
```

And your `changeContent` function would be like

```
function changeContent(url) {

    $.get(url, function(new_content) {
        $('body').html(new_content);
    })

}
```

This will let you change any part of your website without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: That's how to alter the History... i pretty much get that part and know how to do that part. Tho there are some good points in here that i'll have to keep in mind...